# Printing CComBSTR with iostream (std::wcout)

Tags: c++, com, iostream, atl

The following [code](https://rextester.com/ZUOHP37477):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

int main()
{
    CComBSTR bstr(L"test");
    std::wcout << bstr << std::endl;
    std::wcout << static_cast<BSTR>(bstr) << std::endl;
}
```

prints

> 033FA16C
>   test

I tried to investigate which conversions take place in each case with a debugger but both time had stepped into `operator BSTR`. So why the first line prints address while the second prints a text?

Comment: std::wcout doesn't know beans about CComBSTR and the smart type doesn't know beans about iostream.  It gets smarter about BSTR since it is an alias of an alias for wchar_t*.  Not entirely smart enough since a BSTR can store an embedded \0.  Which is not common enough to worry about.

Comment: Beans are not really relevant; the OP reasonably expects the implicit conversion to kick in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove ATL from this entirely, as it's really a question of how `wcout` works.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    operator const wchar_t*() const { return L"what"; };
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::wcout << f << std::endl;
    std::wcout << (const wchar_t*)f << std::endl;
}

// Output:
//   0x400934
//   what
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/890a3211dabb0968))

In your example, [the implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class?view=vs-2019#operator_bstr) from `CComBSTR` to `BSTR` is triggered, but *not* by the template that instantiates `operator<<(const wchar_t*)` (because the conversion is "user-defined", and user-defined conversions are not considered for template parameter matching). The only viable candidate then is the non-template `operator<<(const void*)`, to which your converted `BSTR` is passed.

There's actually a proposal to "fix" this in the standard ([LWG 2342](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2342)) and the text of the proposal explains this in more detail.

In summary:

> For wide streams argument types `wchar_t const*` and `wchar_t` are supported only as template parameters. User defined conversions are not considered for template parameter matching. Hence inappropriate overloads of `operator<<` are selected when an implicit conversion is required for the argument, which is inconsistent with the behavior for `char const*` and `char`, is unexpected, and is a useless result.

The only remaining viable overload is the one taking `const void*` and, since every pointer can implicitly convert to `const void*`, that's what you're getting.

Comment: >You said it was, but it wasn't. -- It's triggering but by a "wrong" overload: operator<<(const void*) rather than operator<<(const wchar_t*), isn't it?

Comment: @vkrzv Close. You said _"both time had stepped into operator BSTR"_ though which, unless something weird is going on, can't be true :) Because the conversion shouldn't be triggered at all. _"User defined conversions are not considered for template parameter matching."_ The overload taking `const wchar_t*` comes from a template.

Comment: But the `const void*` non-template overload is also able to trigger `operator BSTR`. Otherwise where did it get the address from?